# Should topic partitions be replicated across all broker nodes in a Kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, kafka-topic

Though answers are available to question similar to above. My curiosity lies in the fact that suppose n1-5 nodes are in cluster where topics t1 is on n1,n2 and n3, topic t2 is on n3,n4,n5. Now if suppose p1 pushes messages in t1 and c1 consumes from t1 and similarly p2 and c2 for t2.

Here is where I have certain doubts?

1. Assume nodes n3- n5 are all down, now still p1 and c1 will have active connection to cluster which is kind of useless as anyways publishing and consuming fails. (metric connection_count is greater than 0 means there are connections to cluster from either producer or consumer)
2. Is it correct way to replicate a topic to all nodes in a Kafka cluster?
3. Why do we give multiple node address details in bootstrap server property is one address is sufficient?

Note: I am a beginner in Kafka world and still experimenting with local setup to discover potential problems which might occur in real world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Why should it fail? Nodes n1 and n2 are still up and running and assuming that the topic had a `replication-factor=3` all the data should still be accessible.
2. I'd say it depends. It won't harm to replicate the topics across all nodes but sometimes it is redundant (especially when you have a very high number of brokers in the cluster). For high availability, you should set at least `replication-factor=3`. This allows for example one broker to be taken down for maintenance and one more to fail unexpectedly.
3. `bootstrap.servers` is used to setup the connection the Kafka cluster. One address is typically enough to access the whole cluster, but it is always best to provide all the addresses in case one of the servers is down. Note that clients (producers or consumers) make use of all brokers irrespective of which servers are specified in `bootstrap.servers`.

---

Example of 2 topics (each having 3 and 2 partitions respectively):

**Broker 1:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 2       |
|   Partition 1     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 2:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 2    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 2       |
|   Partition 0     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 3:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 1    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

Note that data is distributed (and *Broker 3* doesn't hold any data of *topic 2*).

Topics, should have a `replication-factor` > 1 (usually 2 or 3) so that when a broker is down, another one can serve the data of a topic. For instance, assume that we have a topic with 2 partitions with a `replication-factor` set to 2 as shown below:

**Broker 1:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 2:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 1       |
|   Partition 0     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 3:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 1    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

Now assume that *Broker 2* has failed. *Broker 1* and 3 can still serve the data for topic 1. So a `replication-factor` of 3 is always a good idea since it allows for one broker to be taken down for maintenance purposes and also for another one to be taken down unexpectedly. ***Therefore, Apache-Kafka offers strong durability and fault tolerance guarantees.***

**Note about Leaders:**
At any time, only one broker can be a leader of a partition and only that leader can receive and serve data for that partition. The remaining brokers will just synchronize the data (in-sync replicas). Also note that when the `replication-factor` is set to 1, the *leader* cannot be moved elsewhere when a broker fails. In general, when all replicas of a partition fail or go offline, the `leader` will automatically be set to `-1`.

Comment: But how will data be accessible if all nodes containing the partitions are dead (considering we have replication factor 3 and we have around 5-6 nodes in cluster). Will HA for those consumers will not fail?

Comment: @dvsakgec I've updated my answer using an example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Assume nodes n3- n5 are all down, now still p1 and c1 will have active
>   connection to cluster which is kind of useless as anyways publishing
>   and consuming fails. (metric connection_count is greater than 0 means
>   there are connections to cluster from either producer or consumer)

**Answer:** If all of the three brokers that is your topic replicas are down, then you cannot produce or consume from that topic. To avoid this kind of situations it is recommended to locate brokers in different racks and provide `broker.rack` information in broker configs.

> **broker.rack:** Rack of the broker. This will be used in rack aware
>   replication assignment for fault tolerance. Examples: `RACK1`,
>   `us-east-1d`
>
> Is it correct way to replicate a topic to all nodes in a Kafka
>   cluster?

**Answer:** It is totally up to your fault tolerance needs. If you replicate topic to all 6 brokers, then you can tolerate up to 5 broker failures. (of course `min.insync.replicas` and `acks` configs are also important. If number of replicas is 6, `min.insync.replicas=2`, `acks=all` then you can tolerate up to 4 broker failures to continue sending messages)

> Why do we give multiple node address details in bootstrap server
>   property is one address is sufficient?

**Answer:**`bootstrap.servers` config is used to initial connection to the Kafka cluster. Yes, one address is enough, but what if the broker in this address is down. You cannot connect to cluster. So it's recommended to provide more than one address, to avoid this kind of situation with redundancy.

Comment: I tried that locally and producer was able to connect to other brokers in the cluster and it was able to publish messages in case of single kafka host information is provided

Comment: So your min.insync.replicas=1 in your server.properties (which is default), or your acks producer config parameter is not acks=all. It's a normal behaviour then.

Comment: acks=all and have set the min.insync.replicas=3 which is the number of nodes on which partition of topic exists

Comment: @dvsakgec sorry I misunderstood your previous comment. Of cource you can access cluster and produce message by providing one server address in bootstrap.server.properties. As I said, bootstrap.servers is just for initial connection to cluster and address of one broker is enough.